# Android OpenCV JavaCamera2View Initialisation fail

Tags: java, android, opencv, mat

I try to run the camerapreview on an android device with opencv using JavaCamera2View. I have no trouble with old JavaCameraView.

Here is error message.

> 2018-11-23 13:56:03.199 8034-8052/com.lesafrance.dev.cam2 E/art: No
>   implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int, int,
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer) (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and
>   Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__IIILjava_nio_ByteBuffer_2) 2018-11-23
>   13:56:03.200 8034-8052/com.lesafrance.dev.cam2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: OpenCVCameraBackground
>       Process: com.lesafrance.dev.cam2, PID: 8034
>       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int, int, java.nio.ByteBuffer) (tried
>   Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and
>   Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__IIILjava_nio_ByteBuffer_2)
>           at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
>           at org.opencv.core.Mat.(Mat.java:52)
>           at org.opencv.android.JavaCamera2View$2.onImageAvailable(JavaCamera2View.java:183)
>           at android.media.ImageReader$ListenerHandler.handleMessage(ImageReader.java:687)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

I know that it is common without OpenCV initialisation but in my code, OpenCV has to be started
Here is code

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
     /*
     * JavaCamera2View (CameraBridgeViewBase) Loader
     */
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    // Création des LUT
                    lutBLY = new Mat(1,256,CvType.CV_8UC3);

                    //Here LUT initialisation is ok    

                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView(); //Fail here
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };
```

It fails once enableView() is called, in  createCameraPreviewSession()

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see from this part of the error message that OpenCV is not loaded at all, that is why it can not find an implementation for Mat

> OpenCVCameraBackground Process: com.lesafrance.dev.cam2, PID: 8034
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long
>   org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int, int, java.nio.ByteBuffer) (tried

Try to add a static loader for OpenCV as a workaround, for example add this directly before your BaseLoaderCallback class

```
static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        Log.d("ERROR", "Unable to load OpenCV");
    else
        Log.d("SUCCESS", "OpenCV loaded");
}
```

When it works you should determine whether you need to change to the dynamic loading, or it is good like that.